# Binding Checkbox based on the value of the field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I want to check/uncheck checkbox based on the value of the field `services.Register.IsTest`.

When services.Register.IsTest=True
My checkbox should be checked else not

my checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="patReturned" value="Returned">
```

I am new to AngularJS. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="patReturned" value="Returned" checked="services.Register.IsTest"> will work if services.Register.IsTest is a scope variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are looking for the `ngChecked` directive from AngularJS

> Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside ngChecked is truthy.

Use it like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="patReturned" value="Returned" ng-checked="services.Register.IsTest">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="services.Register.IsTest == true" ng-model="services.Register.IsTest" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) directive if you need two-way binding (i.e. `services.Register.IsTest` will be updated when the checkbox is checked or unchecked):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="patReturned" value="Returned" ng-model="services.Register.IsTest">
```

Make sure `services.Register.IsTest` is a part of the relevant `scope`.

Besides that, you can use [`ng-checked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) directive to avoid changing `services.Register.IsTest`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="patReturned" value="Returned" ng-checked="services.Register.IsTest">
```

Comment: Not going to down vote this but this is not what was asked as this would change the value of servces.register.IsTest if the checkbox is un-checked

Comment: @GeorgeLee If you're talking regarding `ng-model`, yeah, you're right, thanks. I've added a few words to explain this aspect. But the second part of my answer (`ng-checked`) is what we have been asked for.